# Find a degree of the map $f:T\longrightarrow T$, $f(x)=x^k$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Find a degree of the map $f:T\longrightarrow T$, $f(x)=x^k$ where $T=S^1\times S^1$ is the 2-dimensional torus and $x^k=x...x$ is the $k$th power in the group $S^1\times S^1:x^k=(z_1^k,z_2^k)$ for $x=(z_1,z_2)$, $z_1,z_2\in S^1\subset \mathbb{C}$.

This is a question from an old PhD Topology Exam.

Wouldn't the degree of this map just be $k$.. or is that foolish? It can't be that easy.  I guess I'm not quite understanding what the question is asking or looking for.

I guess I'm used to the questions asking about a map from the sphere to the sphere so in that instance we would have a degree $k$ map because you wrap the sphere around itself $k$ times.  But for this question we are dealing with the torus, so I'm assuming when we wrap around the torus it's not quite going to be $k$ many times because of the shape of the torus.

Comment: Shouldn't the degree be $k^2$?

Comment: Could you explain how you got that ?

Comment: Taking the $k$-th power of one of the two coordinates gives you a map of degree $k$, and then you take the composition of these two maps.

Comment: Could you give the two maps you are talking about? Just so I completely understand.

Comment: Let $a_k:(w,z)\mapsto(w^k,z)$ and $b_l:(w,z)\mapsto (w,z^l)$.  Then, $a_k$ is of degree $k$, and $b_l$ is of degree $l$.  Hence, $a_k\circ b_l$ is of degree $kl$.  In particular, $f=a_k\circ b_k$.  You can work the same way for similar maps on the $d$-torus, for any positive integer $d$.

Comment: Okay, yes thank you so much.